# PHP class construction

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to write a simple class:

```
class tempClass 
{
    private $myvar          = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->myvar    = 'temp';
        var_dump($this->myvar);
    }  

    public function getmyvar(){
        return $this->myvar;
    }
}
```

When I call the `getmyvar()` public function from a page I'm including this class on (using the syntax `tempClass::getmyvar();`), shouldn't the `__construct()` method get called automatically before I can access the public function? It doesn't seem to-- I have to do something like:

```
$myclass = new tempClass();
$myclass->getmyvar();
```

in order to have the constructor called. Is there a way to "autoconstruct" this class when calling a class function, rather than having to do the `__construct` code within every function?

Thanks!

Comment: Well-worded question. Thanks for taking the time to use proof-of-concept examples to demonstrate your issue instead of *production* code with needless details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor is called when the object instance is "constructed." In other words, it happens when the instance is created.

When you execute this line:

```
$myclass = new tempClass();
```

a new object is instantiated, and the constructor is executed.

When you use `::` no object is instantiated, so the constructor is not called.

Comment: thanks George-- is there a way to call "self::__construct()" or something like that?

Comment: @julio - Using the `new` keyword as shown above calls `__construct()`.

Comment: @julio: I don't think there is a way to call it directly as a static function, but you may be able to create a method that calls it: `public static function mywrapper() { $this->__construct(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could still make a static call if you wanted, you just need to add a static method to your class:

```
class tempClass
{
    public static function getVar()
    {
        $myclass = new tempClass();

        return $myclass->getmyvar();
    }
}

echo tempClass::getVar();
```

Doesn't look like much now, but in the future you could add more logic, plus it's a good path to start down when you work your way up to factory patterns and singletons.